# Standard deviation calculation - Am I following the right approach? How do we find SD percentage?

Tags: java, standard-deviation, variance, deviation

I have a query which gives me below data.

```
item_name, total_purchase_count_per_week, previous_day_purchase_count.
```

For ex,

```
iPhone , 4800, 200 
Samsung, 3000, 470
Moto, 1700, 80
```

Now, I'm interested in knowing how much percentage yesterday's purchase deviated from previous week purchase of every item.

For Example:

- `5%`, which means yesterday's purchases were higher then previous week's, with a deviation of 5%
- `-11%`, which means yesterday's purchases were lower then previous week's, with a deviation of -11%

This is what I tried:

I wrote a java method, which takes `avg(total_purchase_count_per_week)` and `previous_day_purchase_count` as input to [SummaryStatistics](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html#getStandardDeviation()) and computes SD and variance.

```
 SummaryStatistics txnCountSummary = new SummaryStatistics();

 txnCountSummary.addValue(totalCount);
 txnCountSummary.addValue(avgCountPWeek);

 Double sd = txnCountSummary.getStandardDeviation();
```

This case, SummaryStatistics takes `685` (i.e `4800/7` - average count from previous week) and 200 (yesterday count) gave me SD as `342.94`.

1. Am I calculating SD with correct inputs? just taking the average
   of previous week and calculating SD with yesterday's count is
   enough?
2. If yes, How do we calculate the deviation in percentage?
       like yesterday's purchase is deviated by 5% or -2% compare to
       previous week average as mentioned in the above example.
3. If no, please advice me the right approach to come up with correct
           deviation percentage. I can change the query to pull additional
           details if required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are not asking for the right thing... Also, you should write some sample data from the original tables, because I think you may need not those values for the calculation

Comment: So, there's Standard Deviation calculations, and there's calculating a percentage of change between one number and another. These are two different calcs, [but this is a rough introductory idea](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html) for standard deviation calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is to find the deviation of yesterday's count to the average of last week. This is basically, `(yesterdayCount - (sumOfLastWeekCount/numberOfDaysLastWeek))/(sumOfLastWeekCount/numberOfDaysLastWeek)`

This is different from Standard Deviation which basically measures the degree of spread among a series of data points relative to their average value.([Standard Deviation definition](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html))

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need to use SummaryStatistics in order to achieve that. There is a simple calculation. You just need something like this :

```
lastWeekMedian = total_pruchase_count_per_week / 7;
difference = previous_day_purchase_count - lastWeekMedian; // this can be positive or negative
sd = (100*difference)*1./lastWeekMedian; // your variables should be double/float.
System.out.print(sd + "%"); // print value; for example: 34%;
```

Basically this code calculates what is the difference of the previous day count and the last week median count. An then we calculate what does this difference mean in percents.

For example :

```
If 50 Iphones sold means ..... 100%

Then 25 Iphones difference means .... x%
```